# multiple clustered sql server

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql

Is it possible to have more than 2 servers? (mirror principle) for multiple cluster?

Answer (score 1):

If you mean many nodes per cluster, then yes.

eg 3 primaries, one failover etc

Comment: how? any tutorials?